# How to configure jetty as css/js file server with expires header?

Tags: jetty, expires-header

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="resourceBase"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/foo</Set>
  <Set name="handler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
      <Set name="cacheControl">max-age=3600,public</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
<Set name="virtualHosts">
    <Array type="java.lang.String">
          <Item>foo.bar</Item>
    </Array>
</Set>
</Configure>
```

This is my configuration, but **no expires** header can be added to the http response.

> Because there is no property related to expires header in
>   ResourceHandler.

I found MovedContexHandler have this property, shall i use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make a silly hack to get this work done! If you have a better solution, tell me.

```
package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource;
/**
 * @author jilen.zhang@gmail.com
 * @date 12-7-6
 */
public class StaticResourceHandler extends ResourceHandler{
    private String expires = "xxx";

    @Override
    protected void doResponseHeaders(HttpServletResponse response, Resource resource, String mimeType) {
        super.doResponseHeaders(response, resource, mimeType);
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.EXPIRES, expires);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll do you one better. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23307057/14731 for a Filter that injects arbitrary headers into the response.